# how to config or handle iis when my website change its directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

When I developed and deployed asp.net mvc application in the past,my code is like this:

1. `<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>`
2. `<img src="../../Content/images/logout.png"/>`
3. `<div class="menu_home" style="background-image:url('../../Content/images/menu_home.png');background-color:#919191;"></div>`
4. `$.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: "/Home/Details",
           data: { id: id },
           success: function (jsonResult) {//something}});`

There is no problem while I was testing locally with casini or deploy the website in the iis root directory.

Now when I add application in the iis root, move the application into a new application,I have to rewrite the code forexample in 3:

```
`<img src="url.Content("~/Content/images/logout.png")" /> `
```

in 4

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "myWeb/Home/Details",
    data: { id: id },
    success: function (jsonResult) {//something}});
```

Is there a easy way to do this?forexample:config something or handle something in IIS? My iis version is 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define URL in `url` property like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action(<action name>, <controller name>)'
```

In your case the URL will be something like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Home")'
```

Comment: So I have to rewrite this everywhere in my preoject?Is there a way that i don't need to change the code when I change my website deploy root?

Comment: As far as I know this is the best approach to to handle URLs inside script tags in MVC. This approach will also handle your root problem. But as you are already in the middle of the root directory problem. I think you have to change it everywhere in your project.